# Xcode 8.0 Simulator broken

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

Something has gone wrong with my Xcode install... I was running my app and seeing odd behaviour within the app itself, for starters I wasn't able to run the build in the simulator.. it'd install and never launch, eventually putting up a dialogue box about being unable to bless the connection to the simulator. I'd had this problem a few days before but it eventually went away, googling just revealed people having issues with the beta builds or beta MacOSX.

Eventually today I rebooted my Mac and having done so, launching Xcode gave me some other error about the simulator, which I didn't properly take notice of. Since then my project no longer lists any simulators to deploy with, if i try to add new simulators the button to add the simulator does nothing and I have to cancel the dialogue box. If I try and run the simulator or watch simulator directly it just beach balls indefinitely and i have to force kill it.

I've created a new user account and within that made a new Xcode project, which also has no simulators.

I've got a zipped backup of my Xcode from before this problem occurred which I've extracted and swapped in place and it makes no difference.

I guess I could do with redownloading the app off the AppStore in hope that the installer would do something to fix this problem.

Anyone got any thoughts on other things I can try?!

Cheers

Comment: File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include the contents of ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator and the result of running `sysdiagnose -q`

Comment: What is the output of running `xcrun simctl list` when in this state?

Comment: Thanks, if the issue occurs again I'll definitely do what you suggest. As you've seen it's already fixed now with a reinstall. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is most likely to be the case is that your XCode installation is corrupt. The best thing to do is to delete Xcode entirely and also these directories and files:

- ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.*
- ~/Library/Caches/xctest
- ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.*
- ~/Library/Developer
- ~/Library/MobileDevice
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.*
- ~/Library/SavedState/com.apple.dt.*

Then reboot your system and reinstall Xcode. Hopefully that should have cleared out the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this though obviously trying a different user account account should have removed any ~ files from the equation and grabbing this zipped up Xcode has in theory replaced everything under Xcode. Also not sure how to redownload Xcode, but hopefully that is straightforward once everything is deleted.

Comment: the hope is some backend services are installed by installing Xcode that have gotten broken somehow and don't reside in any of the folders that I've already compensated for, one way or another...

Comment: Thanks.. following these steps has got me back to a functioning Xcode.. not sure how much of the deleted library contents was required or not, also backed them up as was nervous.. annoyingly all my build archives are now empty in Xcode.. not the end of the world but a bit annoying. Thanks for the tips.. hopefully it'll remain stable and work ok now.. at least i know how to fix it if it breaks in the future.. It'll be a nervous few days till i'm confident. First time i push to iTunes will be interesting.. ensure everything is setup ok.

Comment: Cool. Xcode can sometimes get messed up when upgrades occur. Usually when betas are involved. Usually once it's fixed. It remains fine.

Comment: I suspect the only useful thing that you did in all of that was reboot.  Reinstalling likely did nothing as app on disk before and after the install should be 100% exactly the same thing.  Of the paths listed, the only thing relevant to the sim is ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator.

Comment: I'd rebooted countless times, including restore to fix a small hard link count error. My new user on the Mac eliminated any ~/Library files that could have gotten broken for my user. Whatever it was reinstalling fully fixed it. My suspicion is this other service that was failing to bless my simulator connection before breaking fully perhaps got broken. It's still working at the moment so hopefully the issue won't reoccur!