# Issue with ios simulator application on xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Yestarday everything was working fine today come and whenever i try to start application with simulator there is a window saying : Cant boot Simulator.
Sad thing is now that new xcode needs simulators to display it bugs also my storyboards and nibs. tried [Xcode 8.0 Simulator broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031866/xcode-8-0-simulator-broken) the accepted answer here still same bug... plz help :)

Comment: after installing macos Sierra everything start working magically

Comment: If you want help for something like this, you'd need to provide more context.  What error do you see in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log?  Take a sysdiagnose *immediately* after trying to boot the simulator, and file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com