# Xcode 8 freezes on startup while loading any project

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 8 on Xcode started freezing right after launching. I was in the middle of working on two projects so when Xcode starts up it immediately launches the two projects I was working on.
The problem happen when i was discarding some changes on source tree, and when i come back to Xcode i found it not responding.

I tried this solutions with no hope:
1.Rebooted comp - still launches projects and freezes
2.Deleted everything in cache ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData - still launches projects and freezes
3.Also i tried to delete every thing in Autosave Information, but i found the directory empty.

So what i must to do ?

Comment: If it's freezing for just these two projects, you might try [removing `xcuserdata`](http://pinkstone.co.uk/xcode-crashes-every-time-you-open-it-and-how-to-fix-it/). Or, worst case, recreate the projects. If it's freezing regardless of what project you open, the next things to try include (a) reinstalling Xcode; (b) try booting your machine in "[safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)".

Comment: Re installing it, same thing it sill freezing and it opens the prev project i loaded before.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a corrupt installation of Xcode. If it's still not working you could try clearing out Xcode and reinstalling it as per my answer here: [Xcode 8.0 Simulator broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031866/xcode-8-0-simulator-broken/40034075#40034075)

No guarantees, but at least it eliminates the possibility.